# Unable to locate feature 'org.eclipse.equinox.executable'

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-publisher-plugin:2.3.0:publish-products (default-publish-products) on project ------: Publisher failed. Verify your target-platform-configuration and executionEnvironment are suitable for proper resolution: Unable to locate feature 'org.eclipse.equinox.executable'. This feature is required for native product launchers. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
```

Hello everyone, I get the above error when I try to build my project with maven. I've added `org.eclipse.equinox.executable` feature in my target definition. But I have still same error. [part of my target def image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNf34.png)

Comment: Can you show the target definition?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. you need to configure a target platform for you build with "target-platform-configuration" plugin, example is here: https://github.com/eclipse-passage/passage/blob/master/releng/org.eclipse.passage.parent/pom.xml#L527
2. you need to have "org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature.group" added to your target definition, example is here: https://github.com/eclipse-passage/passage/blob/master/releng/org.eclipse.passage.target/org.eclipse.passage.target.target#L23